# Spring batch GC Overhead limit | Spring Batch | JBOSS 6.4

Tags: java, spring-batch, heap-memory

We are using `JBOSS 6.4` - `jdk1.8`, `spring 4.2.1 (batch and integration)`.
Running on `Linux`

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms3g -Xmx3g
```

We have 12 spring batch jobs running parallelly.
They run for about 3 hours fine, after which we start getting GC overhead limit reached errors.

Steps followed so far

1. Increased heap memory from 2g to 3g to find out really how much application would need, even 3g is not sufficing.  We see that the old gen heap space gets filled up after around 3 hours of continuous running of job.
2. Code review to identify any potential leaks, couldn't find any.  Have set some objects to null once their usage is done, but that's pretty much we could get.
3. Added command to generate heap dump on OutOfMemory error
   Below link has details heap dump.  they all point to framework classes, which are not directly referenced within our application.

[Biggest Contributers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaLlN.png) 
[Unreachableobjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaLlN.png)

```
    o   JavaZipFileSystem 28 MB
    o   DefaultListableBeanFactory – 32 MB
    o   ModuleClassLoader – 7 MB
    o   SessionFactoryImpl – 9 MB
    o   String – 6 MB
    o   ThreadGroupContext – 3 MB
```

Any pointers on how to approach identifying the exact root cause please?
Currently we are attempting use Java flight Recorder to get more specific details.

Comment: Maybe you just need more memory. If those batch jobs are doing heavy work, executing 12 at a time might just be too much for your server. Kick it up a notch with more memory, more CPU or scale horizontally.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman.  Though am late in responding, we got to resolve this by increasing the heap memory.  As none of the profiling tool have indicated any issue in the code.